# Which sql query is more secure in terms of SQL injection

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-injection

I have two SQL queries in which I'm trying to update `sup` and `opp` values with +1 and -1 respectively each time the query is called.

First query:

```
    query=update disc set sup=@sup, opp=@opp where did=@did

    int sup=getnoofsup(did);
    int opp = getnoofopp(did);

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sup", sups + 1);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@opp", opps - 1);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@did", did);

    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Second query

```
string query="update disc set sup=sup+1, opp=opp-1 where did=@did" ;
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@did", did);

com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Is there any threat in second query of injection because I exchange `@sup` with `sup+1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the second query is as secure as the first one, because it is fully parameterized, and therefore does not present a path through which an external data could enter the text of the SQL query itself. The `sup+1` expression is calculated by the RDBMS, not by your program<sup>*</sup>, so it cannot present an opportunity to inject new code into the existing SQL.

---

<sup>*</sup> and it is not subsequently presented to SQL's `exec` stored procedure for re-interpretation.

Comment: But the second version lets the SQL server itself do the incrementing. If this may cause weird errors or illegal values you could use the first to check whether sup and opp can be incremented and decremented properly.

Comment: @Davio There may be a way for the query to produce incorrect results, but there is no way to exploit it for SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Both queries are equally secure against Sql Injection but

```
com.Parameters
```

is alway preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Second Query is better.

```
string query="update disc set sup=sup+1, opp=opp-1 where did=@did" ;
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@did", didparameter);
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

both the query are secure but second one is more preferable because u don't need to add extra `parameter`.
In first query u r finding the value of `sup` and `opp` which u don't need to have.